# duplicates with condition

Tags: sql, presto

I would like to get the number of duplicates for `article_id` for each `merchant_id`, where the `zip_code` is not identical. Please see example below:

**Table**

```
merchant_id     article_id   zip_code 
1               4555         1000
1               4555         1003
1               4555         1002
1               3029         1000
2               7539         1005
2               7539         1005
2               7539         1002
2               1232         1006
3               5555         1000
3               5555         1001
3               5555         1002
3               5555         1003
```

**Output Table**

```
merchant_id     count_duplicate
1                3
2                2
3                4
```

This is the query that I am currently using but I am struggling to include the zip_code condition:

```
SELECT merchant_id
       ,duplicate_count
FROM main_table mt 
JOIN(select article_id, count(*) AS duplicate_count
     from main_table
     group by article_id
     having count(article_id) >1) mt_1
ON mt.article_id ON mt_1.article_id = mt.article_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT merchant_id, SUM(num_zips)
FROM (SELECT merchant_id, article_id, COUNT(DISTINCT zip_code) AS num_zips
      FROM main_table
      GROUP BY merchant_id, article_id
     ) ma
WHERE ma.num_zips > 1
GROUP BY merchant_id;
```

Comment: Do you have an idea how I could do it with the condition to only include duplicates where the zip_code is identical?    Would I have to change: 'WHERE ma.num_zups =1'?

Comment: @user12625679 . . . You might want to ask a new question if that doesn't work.